# Remove /page/ in url when opening pages

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

We have added a paging system inside our layout. When we go to /page/clan, the page about our clan gets displayed. (as its located in pages/clan.php).

To get /page, we used a htaccess script, which rewrites index.php?page=*pagename* into the /page/*pagename* I mentioned.

This is our current htaccess code for converting these urls:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^page/([^/]*)$ index.php?page=$1 [L]
```

However, We'd like to remove the /page part, so it's possible to just use /clan instead of /page/clan to open the clan page.

How can this be done and with what code?

Thanks!

Comment: IE, you want redirect all index.php? `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?page=$1 [L]`

Comment: Absolutely now problem, but keep in mind that probably you have some urls that should not be rewritten. So you might have to add exceptions for those.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try :

```
 RewriteEngine On


 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/?$ index.php?page=$1 [L,NC]
```

Rewrite condions make sure you don't rewrite any existing files or directories on the server.

**[NC]** flag makes the pattern case insensitive,  so in you case example.com/fOo would also work.

Comment: Hm, how can I dont rewrite rule for one rule? I have a folder called phpBB, where a forum is in located, which breaks because this rule. :(